# BigQuery query_parameters null

Tags: google-bigquery

How to set a query parameter be null?

```
query = """
SELECT word, word_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
WHERE corpus = @corpus
AND word_count >= @min_word_count
ORDER BY word_count DESC;
"""

query_params = [
bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('corpus', 'STRING', 'romeoandjuliet'),
bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('min_word_count', 'INT64', 250)
]
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters = query_params
```

if I want the corpus be null, how can i code it?

Comment: In SQL, equals with NULL returns NULL, so I don't think that is what you want (you would need to write `corpus IS NULL` instead). Is there some other example that you have in mind where you would want a NULL query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you specify a value of `None` for the query parameter:

```
query = """
SELECT word, word_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
WHERE corpus = @corpus
AND word_count >= @min_word_count
ORDER BY word_count DESC;
"""

query_params = [
bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('corpus', 'STRING', None),
bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('min_word_count', 'INT64', 250)
]
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters = query_params
```

As I suggested in the comment above, though, this probably isn't what you want in this particular case, since the comparison `corpus = @corpus` (where the query parameter is `NULL`) will always return `NULL`, so you won't get back any results from this query.